# How to add id HTML attribute in ASP.NET MVC w/ VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am trying to add an ID HTML attribute to a form using ASP.NET MVC and VB.NET

```
<%Html.BeginForm("Create", "Model", "", "", New With {.id = "CreateForm"})%>
```

This gives me a type error, since .id is expecting an Integer, not a string. How do add an ID attribute to my form?

Comment: what language are you trying this in?  VB or C#?

Comment: VB (see title and description) ;)

Comment: i would like to know the answer to this question as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you need something like this

```
<%  Html.BeginForm("Create", "Model", 
    FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "CreateForm"})%>
```

I think it's trying to cast one of your empty strings as the FormMethod enumeration, which won't cast correctly.

Either way check this link out, it has all the overloads for the BeginForm method.

[Html.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542.aspx)

Comment: you dont get intellisense whwen you type the . (dot) do you? that is, in New With {.   - no intellisense right?

Comment: No because you're creating an anonymous type, so there's nothing that intellisense can provide you in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Close:

```
<%Html.BeginForm("Create", "Model", "", "", new {id = "CreateForm"})%>
```

Comment: This gives me a compilation error.  I'm pretty sure this will work in C#, but not VB.NET

Comment: Ahh.. Sadly, I didn't see the VB indicators. Sorry.