# How can I apply a top margin to my Html.BeginForm

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have this code:

```
<div class="mdl_bdy_frm">
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") 

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.UserName, new { @class = "adm" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login.UserName, new { @class = "adm", size = 30 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.UserName)

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.Password, new { @class = "adm" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Login.Password, new { @class = "adm", size = 30 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.Password)
            <br />
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Login.RememberMe, new { @class = "adm" })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login.RememberMe, new { @class = "adm" })

            <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>

        }
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can give my HTML.BeginForm at top-margin style?  If possible I would like to do this with an inline style as its just used in the one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Html.BeginForm( ..., ..., ..., New With {.style = "margin-top:20px;"})
```

See: [How to add id HTML attribute in ASP.NET MVC w/ VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836015/how-to-add-id-html-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-w-vb-net)

Answer (score 5):

You could just add `padding` to the parent `div`.

`<div class="mdl_bdy_frm" style="padding-top:20px;">`

Comment: I can't do this because my parent div has a solid border :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { style = "margin: 10px;" }))
```